# Twig iterate over object properties

Tags: php, twig

I read in the Twig documentation that it is possible to iterate over an associative array in the following manner:

```
{% for key, value in array %}  
 {{key}}  
 {{value}}  
{% endfor %}
```

I was wondering whether this is possible for objects of type stdClass as well.

I would have expected Twig to iterate over the property values of the object taking the property names as keys. Instead, the instruction block contained in the for loop is not executed at all.

Comment: What means "it _does not seem_ to work"?

Comment: @KingCrunch It means that it did not work when I tried it, but I might be doing something wrong. I'm interested whether it is a feature supported by the templating engine. I'll edit my message for clarity.

Comment: @Bodgan What I tried to ask: What happens _instead_? ;)

Comment: @KingCrunch It does not iterate at all over the object's properties, with the syntax that I provided above.

Comment: @KingCrunch To be more precise, it simply ignores the construct and continues rendering. It does not cause an exception to be raised.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can first cast the object to array. You can build own filter casting your object to array. More about filters is available here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#filters

It could then look like that:

```
{% for key, value in my_object|cast_to_array %}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, Tadeck. I have used the solution you proposed prior to writing this question. I'm currently using get_object_vars in the PHP controller to convert the object to an array, but I was curious whether there is a functionality in Twig which would allow me to avoid processing the object in the controller. It seems reasonable to me to expect the objects to be processed in the same manner as arrays in this particular case.

Comment: I'll accept your answer since at least it provides a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 11):

To complete Tadeck's answer here is how:

If you have not ever created or setup a Twig extension (filter), you will need to follow this instruction first http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

1) add to your AppBundle/Twig/AppExtension.php ('cast_to_array')

```
public function getFilters()
{
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFilter('md2html', array($this, 'markdownToHtml'), array('is_safe' => array('html'))),
        new \Twig_SimpleFilter('price', array($this, 'priceFilter')),
        new \Twig_SimpleFilter('cast_to_array', array($this, 'objectFilter')),
    );
}
```

2) add to your AppBundle/Twig/AppExtension.php

```
public function objectFilter($stdClassObject) {
    // Just typecast it to an array
    $response = (array)$stdClassObject;

    return $response;
}
```

3) In your example.html.twig loop thru with twig and the filter.

```
{% for key, value in row|cast_to_array %}
       <td id="col" class="hidden-xs">{{ value }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Done, I hope it helps. From Tadeck's pointer.

Answer (score 9):

After loading TWIG, add this filter:

```
$twig->addFilter( new Twig_SimpleFilter('cast_to_array', function ($stdClassObject) {
    $response = array();
    foreach ($stdClassObject as $key => $value) {
        $response[] = array($key, $value);
    }
    return $response;
}));
```

It's named **cast_to_array** after [Tadeck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548696/tadeck)'s suggestion. :)
I'm sure it doesn't work for any kind of *stdClass Object*, but it sure solved my problem with printing PHP *associative arrays* :) Use it as follows:

```
{% for key, value in my_object|cast_to_array %}
    <td>{{ value.1 }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

## Side story

Since I got into this SO page a lot, I think it's pertinent to show where I'm using Twig for *iterating over object properties*, so it's helpful for other people with the same problem:
I was trying to print a table from a .json source, but PHP's json_decode transforms any *"key" : "value"* into a PHP associative array, which Twig doesn't print by default.
So this filter cuts and delivers a regular array to be used by Twig.

### source.json

```
{
    "user": {
        "family": {
            "table": [{
                "First_Name": "John",
                "Last_Name": "Foo",
                "Age": 25,
                "Role": "Brother"
            }, {
                "First_Name": "Mary",
                "Last_Name": "Bar",
                "Age": 14,
                "Role": "Sister"
            }, {
                "First_Name": "Joe",
                "Last_Name": "Baz",
                "Age": 33,
                "Role": "Uncle"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

### Twig

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr> {# get table headers from the table row #}
      {% for row in user.family.table.0|cast_to_array %}
        <th>{{ row.0 | replace({'_': ' '}) }}</th>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for row in user.family.table %}
      <tr>
      {% for key, value in row|cast_to_array %}
        <td>{{ value.1 }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just do:


    $twig->addFilter(new Twig_SimpleFilter('cast_to_array', function ($stdClassObject) {
        return (array)$stdClassObject;
    }));

Comment: Objects can be iterated just like arrays, Twig should provide the functionality, instead of taking it away and forcing unnecessary data massaging.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is old but, wouldn't

```
$assoc_array = json_decode(json_encode($stdClassObject), TRUE);
```

work just as well?

Comment: Please only answer a question you understand. This is PHP code. The question is about Twig code.

Answer (score 5):

In case this helps someone else.  You can have Twig iterate the properties of your object provided you implement PHP's Iterator interface.

In my case I have a generic object the uses the magic methods __get(), __set(), __isset(), and __unset() while storing key value pairs in a private array.  This works fine in Twig until you want to iterate over the object using something like this

```
<ul>
{% for prop, value in object %}
    <li>{{prop|replace({'_': ' '})|title}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

To make it work I had to implement the Iterator interface.  Then the above code worked perfectly.

Now because of the magic __get() the property names are not case sensitive either so each of these work also.

```
<ul>
{% for object in arrayOfObjects %}
    <li>{{ object.property }}</li>
    <li>{{ object.Property }}</li>
    <li>{{ object.PROPERTY }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  {% for key, item in content.field_invoice_no if key|first != '#' %} <tr>
      <td>{{ item }}</td>
       <td> {{ content.field_invoice_date[key]  }}     </td>
       <td> {{ content.field_invoice_price[key]   }}       </td>
       </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Iterating object over key value

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out a vanilla Twig solution. I make use of the reduce filter to transform an object to an array.

Let's say we get an address object from the backend and want to convert it into an associative array in order to render each line separate.

```
{% set address = { firstName: 'Stack', lastName: 'Overflow', address: 'here', zipCode: '1234' } %}
```

We reduce the keys and add them to an empty array

```
{% set addressLines = address|keys|reduce((carry, key) => carry|merge({ (key): attribute(address, key) }), []) %}
```

This results in:

```
[ 'firstName' => 'Stack', 'lastName' => 'Overflow', 'address'=> 'here', 'zipCode' => '1234' ]
```

Now we can render this in a for loop

```
{% set allowedKeys = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'address'] %}
{% for key, line in addressLines|filter((v, k) => k in allowedKeys) %}
    {{ line }}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

add function array to twing and call in template array(value)

```
$loader = new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader('templates/'.$path);
$twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader,['debug' => true]);
$function_2 = new \Twig\TwigFunction('array', function ($value) {
    return (array)$value;
});
$twig->addFunction($function_1);
```