# Three nested for-loops do not seem to work

Tags: php, symfony, for-loop, nested, twig

I'm currently working on a website project on Symfony 2.8.
But I have a problem : I want to display information from a JSON object. However, I need to do three nested for-loops in order to do what I want.

So here's my code chunks :

The array I want to browse :

```php
element stdClass Object =>
(
[partschemes] => Array
(
    [0] => ( [id] => 1 )
)
[decodedPartitions] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [partitions] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => WINDOWS
                                [type] => primary
                                [size] => -
                                [filesystem] => fat32
                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => DATA*
                                [type] => primary
                                [size] => 256 Mo
                                [filesystem] => fat32
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
)
```

My twig template :

```html
{% for i, disk in element.decodedPartitions %}
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center" rowspan="3" width="10%">
                <a href="{{ app.request.baseUrl }}/partscheme/details/{{ element.partschemes[i].id }}" class="btn btn-info" title="{{ 'button.details' | trans }}">Disk {{ i }}</a>
            </th>
        </tr>

        {% for j, part in disk.partitions %}
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center" width="10%">Partition {{ j }}</th>
            <td>
                {% for k, partInfo in part %}
                    {{ k }}: {{ partInfo }}<br>
                {% endfor %}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

And as a result, the generated page shows me that, without information of different partitions:

```
---------------------------------
       | Partition 0 |          |
Disk 1 |-------------|----------|
       | Partition 1 |          |
---------------------------------
```

Comment: You can't iterate over object properties directly in twig (`part` is object, not an array!). You can either change exported variable, so that `part` is array, or you can query concrete attributes, like `part.name`, `part.type`, ... or you can cast the object to array with custom filter, like decribed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841515/twig-iterate-over-object-properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Miro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2615041/miro), I was able to iterate over my JSON object.

The reason was that it is not possible to iterate over an stdClass object directly in Twig. So I added a parameter in my `json_decode` use in the controller.

To convert a JSON into an stdClass object : `json_decode($json)`

To convert a JSON into an associative array : `json_decode($json, true)`

More information about [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php).