# Symfony3/Twig templating: database object to table

Tags: php, mysql, twig, symfony

I'm just learning Symfony3 and Twig. Unsure what I'm doing wrong, but I have a DB table *product* with rows ***'name', 'price' and 'description'***. I want to simply dump the DB table into an HTML table. I did as follows:

**Twig:**

```
<table>
    {% for product in products %}
        <tr>
            {% for key,value in product %}
                <td>{{ value }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

if I dump **product** at the beginning of the first for-loop, I get the following result:

```
Product {#330 ▼
  -id: 1
  -name: "Keyboard"
  -price: "19.99"
  -description: "Ergonomic and stylish!"
}
```

however, **key** and **value** are both empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twig iterate over object properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841515/twig-iterate-over-object-properties)

Comment: You're trying to iterate over object properties, something that is not possible by default. You'll need to cast the object to an array first

Comment: You seem to be right, but it also seems unnecessarily laborious for a system that was made to make things easier.

Comment: imho you shouldn't be looping it's properties.. You should do stuff like : `{% for product in products %}<h1>{{ product.getName() }}</h1><p>{{ product.getDescription() }}<span class="price">${{ product.getPrice() }}</p>`

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th> <th>Price</th> <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    {% for product in products %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ product.getName }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.getPrice }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.getDescription }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

The code depends on your getters.

Comment: Or, more succinctly, you can use use `product.name`, `product.price`, etc.  Twig will automatically detect and use your getters, as long as they're named according to the typical convention.

Comment: Well yes, I guess I formulated my question somewhat inaccurately. I'm supposing I don't know that you have name, price and description in this object, and I want to simply output key > value of whatever object I get, i.e. replicate the table in the MySQL DB.

Comment: The `dump` shows what's in your results. Have you tried my solution? Also @SamDufel is correct, you can use that method two; however, it may not always work depending on your design.

Comment: Hi, yes those work. But that supposes that I know which elements are in the object. What if I don't? Like when you just select every column from a DB table and display what's in the table.

I guess that's not what we're supposed to do now that there are objects and such.

Comment: You're looking at this the wrong way - when you use an ORM such as Doctrine, your entity class is the definition of your data structure.  Don't think about the column names; those are going to be mapped to fields in the object for you.

Comment: Thanks, Sam. I did indeed come from Plain PHP and am just going through the tutorials on the Symfony website.