# loop through key values of an array in twig

Tags: twig

I have not been able to find my answer elsewhere (maybe because I didn't know how to ask google as I'm pretty new to this ;))

I'm working with symfony and twig.

I pass an array in my view with only one entry related to the id. It looks like this in my view

```
    array:2 [▼
  "sponsor" => Sponsor {#473 ▼
    -id: 5
    -sponsorCode: "FUT"
    -name: "MANULO"
    -city: "OLERDOLA"
    -zipCode: 0
    -address: ""
    -country: "ESPANA"
    -phoneNumber: 32767
    -email: ""
    -creationDate: DateTime {#470 ▶}
  }
  "app" => AppVariable {#476 ▶}
]
```

I know I can access each property by doing

```
{{sponsor.name}}
```

But I'm trying to do it through a loop for each field of this array

something like

```
{% for key, value in sponsor %}
   <div class="field-group">
     <div class="field">{{ key }}:</div>
     <div class="value">{{ value }}</div>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Am I missing something?

Thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twig iterate over object properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841515/twig-iterate-over-object-properties)

Comment: Any error message or incorrect result from you attempt? Please also read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to refine the question whenever needed.

Comment: No error message, It symply doesn't loop on what I want. I'm looking through the possible duplicate question but I'm really surprised this is not a feature of twig.

Answer (score 2):

From the TWIG documentation:

**Keys Only**

By default, a loop iterates over the values of the sequence. You can iterate on keys by using the keys filter:

```
<h1>Members</h1>
<ul>
    {% for key in users|keys %}
        <li>{{ key }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**Keys and Values**

You can also access both keys and values:

```
<h1>Members</h1> <ul>
    {% for key, user in users %}
        <li>{{ key }}: {{ user.username|e }}</li>
    {% endfor %} </ul>
```

https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/for.html

Keep your eye on the TWIG documentation, its rather comprehensive.

Looking at your code, it looks ok. However, the issue could be that the `{{value}}` may need further identification, such as `{{ value.id }}`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did read this part of the documentation but I think it is more related to if I had an array with multiple entries. This is not what I'm trying to do. In my case I want to loop on the values inside the array. As you see in the documentation inside their loop they are doing {{ user.username|e }}. I'm trying to loop for not having to write {{ user.username|e }} for each fields

Comment: OP is trying to loop object properties, which is not possible by the default `for`-loop in `twig`