# How to pass entire objects from Controller to Twig in Symfony 3?

Tags: arrays, symfony, twig, key-value-store

I'm triyng to pass an object to Twig.
The object is the representation of an Entity, obtained via the

```
getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(/*repoName*/)->find(id);
```

This actually works but how can I display all of its values in a html table in Twig?
I tried serialization but with no success, maybe I am missing something, please help.
Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
What I actually want to achieve is to iterate to that object WITHOUT knowing its keys, a sort of

```
foreach (field in object) print key, value
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$object = $em->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(/*repoName*/)->find(id);
```

You need pass this variable to the template by :

```
return $this->render('Anypath/your_template.html.twig', ['obj'=>$object]);
```

than from the twig :

`{{obj.id}}` or `{{obj.name}}`

depends on your fields inside object.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller:

```
  return $this->render('path/template.html.twig', ['entity'=>$entity]);
```

and in your template (replace your_attribute_name by any attribute of your entity):

```
{{ entity.your_attribute_name }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you send your object to you twig template

```
return $this->render("AppBundle:Records:template.html.twig", [
        "$object" => $object
    ]);
```

You can just do:

```
{{ object.field }}
```

That correspond to doing `$object->getField()` in `PHP`

Then just build your list manually in your twig

You you wanna loop through your object have a look at thise subject 
[Twig iterate over object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841515/twig-iterate-over-object-properties)

```
{% for key, value in my_object|cast_to_array %}
```

This might help