# Show a multidimensional array in twig

Tags: symfony, for-loop, twig

I have a query in `DQL` that in response generates a multidimensional array in this way:

[image]

How do I show this on screen with twig?

Comment: what do you want to show, array or show array values in the table

Comment: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html

Comment: I want to show the values that are inside each array, That link works for a simple array. It does not work for my problem

Comment: {% for value in youArray%}
        <li>{{ yourArray.username }}</li>
    {% endfor %}

Comment: That's because this is not a multi-dimensional array, but an array with objects. Twig can't itterate object properties by default

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twig iterate over object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841515/twig-iterate-over-object-properties)

Comment: So how can this be solved?
If I make 2 queries to the database is it solved or do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Watch the question i've tagged... `{% for object in array %}{% for key, value in object|cast_to_array %}{{ key }}: {{ value }}{% endfor %{% endfor %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution.
Thanks to the help of [DarkBee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/446594/darkbee)
I saw this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402216/2400373 which adapts to my problem.
It presents other problems here I explain

My DQL is this:

```
$dql="SELECT c,o
      FROM BackendBundle:Orders o
      JOIN o.users u
      JOIN BackendBundle:Customer c
      WITH u.email =  c.billEmail
      where o.orderid='$var'";
```

After it's necessary to add a twig extension:

```
//src/AppBundle/Twig/AppExtension.php
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Twig/AppExtension.php
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('cast_to_array', array($this, 'objectFilter')),
        );
    }

    public function objectFilter($stdClassObject) {
        // Just typecast it to an array
        $response = (array)$stdClassObject;

        return $response;
    }
}
```

After in twig:

```
{% for key, value in ordenes|cast_to_array %}
     <td id="col" class="hidden-xs">{{ value }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Other problems in my Entities I need add __toString ... for example:

```
public function __toString()
{
   return (string)$this->getBillEmail();
}
```

With this already works. thank you help