# Loop twig object

Tags: loops, object, twig

i have an object like this:

```
> object(stdClass)#526 (2) { ["0"]=> object(stdClass)#525 (2) { 
["title"]=> string(8) "title 1" 
["text"]=> string(11) "paragraph 1" 
} 
["1"]=> object(stdClass)#527 (2) { 
["title"]=> string(8) "title 2" 
["text"]=> string(11) "paragraph 2" 
} 
}
```

how can i loop it in twig?
if i do:

```
{% for paragraph in data.data.extraDescription.0.contents.paragraphs %}

{{ dump(paragraph.title)  }}
{% endfor %}
```

it doens't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841515/twig-iterate-over-object-properties

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you getting an error?