# Twig include only an object in a template

Tags: twig

I have an array of objects and am iterating over them in twig as follows

```
{% for thing in things %}

   {{ include 'template.html' with thing only }}

{% endfor %}
```

If `things` is an array of arrays, this works as intended, is it possible to do with an array of objects instead ? When using an array of objects I get array expected, got Object

I can't seem to cast in the include statement.

Answer (score 1):

As you did not post `template.html`, I'm guessing the template either looks like:

A) Referencing `thing` in the template

```
<h1>{{ thing.title }}</h1>
<p>{{ thing.content|raw }}</p>
```

B) Using extracted properties of the object in the template

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
<p>{{ content|raw }}</p>
```

---

If your template look like **A**, it will suffice to just change the include to the following,

1. You don't care if the whole context is send to `template.html`

```
{% for thing in things %}
    {% include 'template.html' %}
{% endfor %}
```

2. You don't want to send the context to `template.html`

```
{% for thing in things %}
    {% include 'template.html' with { 'thing': thing, } only %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

If your template look like **B**, then you will have some "more" work to solve the issue. Twig is not able to (iterate/extract)* an object properties by default, to do this you would need to [cast the object to an array first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841515/twig-iterate-over-object-properties). Then you would be able to access the different properties of the object inside `template.html`, like shown in template **B**

```
{% for thing in things %}
    {% include 'template.html' with thing|cast_to_array only %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

***** *By iterating/extracting the properties of an object, I mean that if you'd passed an object as you posted in your question, the properties will not be magically available in the template by default, so if your class had the properties `title` and `content`, these will* **not** *be available like the example I've added as* **B**

Comment: I am using B. When using cast_to_array I get this Unknown "cast_to_array" filter

Comment: Check the question i've linked in my answer for that function - This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402216/446594)