# Loop through array in object value Twig

Tags: php, twig

Very simple yet I'm not familiar with the syntax. This is my array:

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "title": "product",
            "ID": "1",
            "price": "€ 85,00 ",
            "discount": "€ 59,50 ",                
            "discountperc": "30 %",
            "stars": "2",
            "prodnew" : "",
            "images": "http://127.0.0.1/image.png"
        },
        {
            "title": "product"
            "ID": "2",
            "price": "€ 180,00 ",
            "discount": "",
            "discountperc": "",
            "stars": "",
            "prodnew" : "",
            "images": "http://127.0.0.1/image.png"
        },
```

I'm trying to achieve the following

```
{% for item in dummy.products %}
{{item.title}}
{
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "{{item.title}}",
  "price": "item.price",
  "image": "item.images"
},
{% endfor %}
```

It'doesnt render anything and it doesn't give me errors it's wrong the approach with the array

Comment: It's not possible to iterate through an object's properties by default.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Twig iterate over object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841515/twig-iterate-over-object-properties)